# jQuery UI Checkbox not showing

Tags: jquery-ui

I have:

```
<input name="ShowDeleted" type="checkbox" />
<label for="ShowDeleted">Show Deleted</label>
```

and in my JavaScript, I have:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').button();
```

The way that I call that I call jQuery is:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="myGoodness.js"></script>
```

And then the Javascript is:

```
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.load("jqueryui", "1");
var myLoadCallback = function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').button();
};
google.setOnLoadCallback(myLoadCallback);
```

Q: Why am I not seeing a jQuery UI styled checkbox?  Is it because myLoadCallback is being called after jQuery loads but before jQuery UI loads?

In Firebug, I see that the input has class ui-helper-hidden-accessible added to it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it work like this.

[See Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGRQ3/)

The `for` element on your `label` should be referencing an `ID`.

I changed your `input` to include `id="check"` and changed your `label` from `for="ShowDeleted"` to `for="check"`.

```
<input name="ShowDeleted" type="checkbox" />
<label for="ShowDeleted">Show Deleted</label>
```

to

```
<input id="check" name="ShowDeleted" type="checkbox" />
<label for="check">Show Deleted</label>
```

And then I just called the following Javascript to create the jquery checkbox button.

```
$('#check').button();
```

If these changes do not work for you, id suggest making sure that you are pulling in the jquery and jquery-ui js and css files properly.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the [for](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for) attribute of your `<label>` element must refer to the `id` attribute of the check box, not to its `name`.

Adding an `id` attribute to the check box fixes your problem:

```
<input id="ShowDeleted" name="ShowDeleted" type="checkbox" />
<label for="ShowDeleted">Show Deleted</label>
```